# Can I make the toolbar buttons in TextEdit bigger?

Tags: macos, accessibility, textedit

The toolbar buttons at the top of TextEdit windows are extremely small compared to every other app that uses a toolbar (e.g. Finder).

[image: TextEdit Window]

Is there any way to make these buttons bigger without changing my Mac's resolution or anything that affects other apps? I'm using macOS 10.15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - this app follows the system Accessibility controls (zoom and hover text and Displays to choose larger text) and does not have any configuration to change itself independently of the user settings.

The [free editor BBEdit](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/bbedit/id404009241) has controls you seek - so if you can't let TextEdit do your bidding, other editors should have what you need in terms of editing and controlling the icon size of the status bar and controls.

Comment: [TextEdit is open source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/TextEdit) (although this code appears to be 10 years out of date) so could someone just create a fork of TextEdit with bigger toolbar buttons?